# How to get a row with maximum no of columns in excel

Tags: java

In my case i want to get the maximum used last column index in a sheet

For eg this is the excel sheet which i have

```
Action  Company Name     Company Code     Product Name      Product Code
new        AAA            A 1                ABC    
update     BBB            B 1                DEF               B-1
new        CC             C 1
```

Here, I know that "getLastCellNum()" will give the last column in particular row. but what i need is to get the maximum column index that is used in entire sheet. say for example i should last Cell Number as "5" in this case. Is there any method to find this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRqnO.png)
Explanation :
Here i looped each row and checked last Cell Number of current row is greater than previous row's last Cell Number. if s i saved it in the result variable. it sounds not a good practice in case if the sheet contains more no.of rows.

Is there any other way of finding last Cell Index or the row which contains maximum column, instead of iterating each row..?
Expected output is:

```
   lastCellIndex = 5
```

Comment: I don't think there is a method doing this for you. You should iterate over the sheet row by row and search the "last cell"

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. But is there any other simplest way..? can u pls explain it in detail